# How to find parent document?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

This is my 2 schemas:

```
var activationTokenSchema = new Schema({
  token: String,
});

var userSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  login: String,
  email: String,
  password: String,
  balance: Number,
  isActivated: Boolean,
  activationToken: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'ActivationToken' }
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
const ActivationToken = mongoose.model('ActivationToken', activationTokenSchema);
```

`User` is parent model, which has child model `ActivationToken`. 
Having only `token` string, how can I find User document?
Or is it better to redesign `ActivationTokenSchema` and include `userId` there, so only child will be pointing to parent?